# Cleaning Up Temporary File after Returning to Browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller action that dynamically generates a PowerPoint file.  This happens currently by unzipping an existing .pptx file, applying some changes to the XML, and zipping up the result into a new, temporary .pptx file.  That file is then returned from the action using File().

How can I clean up the temporary file after it has been returned to the client?

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Personally, I add an async process on each call to cleanup-- it's also how I update cache, do logging, etc... You are GOING to have another call, use it. It's just the nature of the web-- you COULD do a hack with a poller or something, but it's best to stick with the on-demand model of HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a wrapper class that implements `IDisposable` that is responsible for both creating the temporary file and deleting it in Dispose().

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using a library such as `SharpZipLib`.

The correct solution IMO is not to generate the file in the first place. With `SharpZipLib` you could just write the file to a `stream`. Just point it to the outputstream and you should be good.

Comment: I'm actually using System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive, but I guess the same should apply.  How and when will the stream be disposed if it is used instead of a file?

Comment: If you use the OutputStream as your underlying stream, the framework will close it for you when it sends the request back.

Comment: How exactly do I return a stream?  I only see examples of getting all bytes from a stream and returning all of the bytes using File.